# Create new table from sum of existing table rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table named iput which has 12 months INDs as follow
[image: table that already has created]

and want to create a new table named output as follow
[image: out put demo which I supposed]
in output, the first month is its self, second month is first month Plus second month, third month is first month plus second plus third month, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  i1.date,
        SUM(IFNULL(i2.ind, 0)) + i1.ind AS ind
  FROM  iput i1
    LEFT JOIN iput i2 ON i2.date < i1.date
  GROUP BY i1.date
  ORDER BY i1.date;
```

The query takes each row in `iput`, joins to every other row in `iput` that happened *before* this row, and adds the value of the `ind` column together.

Sample output:

```
date        ind
2019-01-01  5959684354
2019-01-02  17830250708
2019-01-03  35695117062
2019-01-04  59548261416
```

This assumes that `ind` is a numeric column of some type.